# Save PDF as JPEG, but only specific pages not full pdf

Tags: pdf, jpeg

I have a pdf of +50 pages. I want to save page 25 as a jpeg. Is this possible to do without saving the full pdf as jpeg?

Comment: On which system? What have you tried so far? What the page looks like, is it image or text? Why can't you do the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Import the PDF on [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/), it will show a dialog where you select the page(s) you want to convert.

[image]

Then Export as *some_name.jpg*.

Answer (score 0):

Take a screenshot of the page. A great tool for this is [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/), which let's you crop your selection as you take the screenshot, and export in various ways.

If you don't want to use third party tools, you can do this easily in Windows with only Adobe Reader and Paint.

1. In Adobe Reader, click Edit, "Take a Snapshot"

[image]

2. Click and drag the area of the page you want to save
3. Right click the select and Copy

[image]

4. Open MS Paint, paste your selection, and save as a JPEG

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your PDF contains vector art that you would like to retain in high quality so that you can export a higher resolution image then [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) is an option.

When you open a PDF file it will open a dialog asking which page you want to load and some extra options.

It can import PDFs and export them in either a raster image (png) or it can export in a vector format such as `svg` or `emf` which can result in a lot higher quality outputs.

I find `emf` files created from pdfs via Inkscape will give very good quality printed output when inserted into Word documents, especially when the source is a technical drawing.

Comment: Nice, this looks good, my pdf will have images and art in it.

Comment: It's definitely a little clunky as tools go, but it is surprisingly good at what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can with Sejda's online [PDF to JPG converter](https://www.sejda.com/pdf-to-jpg):

1. Open https://www.sejda.com/pdf-to-jpg in your browser.
2. Select your PDF file.
3. On the page you'd like to convert (Eg: page 25) click **Save as JPG**.

The page will be converted to an image and saved to your local computer.

[image: How to convert a PDF page to JPG image using Sejda.com]

Disclaimer: I'm one of the devs.